# MS Excel 2010 push a value to another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Column A has values manually input each week.
I want to show that value in a different cell C1.
e.g.
The value of A1 to be shown in C1 then when A2 has a value it overwrites the previous value in C1 and when A3 has a value it overwrites the previous value in C1 and so on.
So the current value in column is automatically shown in cell C1.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

E.g.:
`=OFFSET(A1,COUNT(A:A)-1,0)`

Note: this works only if you fill column A without gaps.

Comment: For me this produces this error 'You've entered too few arguments for this function'.

Comment: I've typed it from phone,  couldn't check,  please try the corrected version.